# Outlook appointment via excel VBA issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to do the following. The code below all works fine, but the range being copied and pasted comes above the body of the e-mail whereas I need it below. Any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm adding ranges and items after the body, I append the new items onto the old, so i can control the order, using `HTMLBody` as opposed to just `Body`:

```
.HTMLBody = _
    "<HTML><body>All;<br><br>" & _
    "Text " & singleCellValue & ".<br><br></body></HTML>"
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & CopyRangeToHTML(rangeOfCells)
```

Some notes:

- A single value taken from a range can be included in the text wherever, e.g., `singleCellValue`
- The double HTML breaks are doubled to 1) get you to the next line, and 2) add another line... I don't tend to have spacing indentations, so keep that in mind if you do
- The use of a `rangeOfCells` is performed via a function, slightly modified from an old Rob de Bruin function to allow copying of conditional formatting:

```
Private Function CopyRangeToHTML(ByVal n As Range)
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, temp As String
    Dim wbs As Workbook: Set wbs = n.Worksheet.Parent
    temp = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".htm"
    With wbs.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange, Filename:=temp, Sheet:=n.Worksheet.Name, Source:=n.Address, HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(temp).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    CopyRangeToHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    Kill temp
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set wbs = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry just so I understand where do the two pieces of code you just posted fit into the original posted code?

Comment: @studentuni998 the function is a separate function within the same module and the `.HTMLBody` items would replace use of `.Body` as referenced in `OutMeet`.

Comment: @Cyril, sorry I'm still lost. Could you explain further how I would input this new code into my old code I can't get it to run.

Comment: @studentuni998 please post what you've tried as an update to your post so I can see what you've tried.  I do not know if you attempted to declare/dimension your ranges or how you implemented the language for `HTMLBody` in lieu of `Body`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify **CreateAppointment** procedure by setting your range and the recipients.
Read the comments for better understanding. Your range will be copied to an htm temporary file with **RangetoHTML**.

In order to create an appointment in HTML format, an temporary email is created in this format in background and then it's content is copied to the appointment.

```
Public Sub CreateAppointment()
    Dim olApp As Object     ' Outlook application
    Dim olApt As Object     ' Outlook Appointment Item
    Dim olMail As Object    ' Outloot Mail Item
    Dim greetings As String
    
    Dim RowCount As Long: RowCount = 5

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    
    ' Define your range HERE
    Dim rangeOfCells As Range: Set rangeOfCells = Range(Cells(3, 12), Cells(RowCount + 2, 24))
    
    ' Greetings
    greetings = "Hi," & vbCrLf
    
    With olApt
        .Display
        .Start = Date & " 09:10"
        .Duration = 90
        .Subject = "Report XXX"
        .Location = "Office - XX"
        
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Put the HTML into the mail item, then copy and paste to appt
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        ' Copy rante to mail body
        olMail.HTMLBody = greetings & RangetoHTML(rangeOfCells)
        ' Copy from mail
        olMail.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy
        ' Paste mail in Appointment
        olApt.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Paste
        ' Close mail without saving
        olMail.Close False
        
        ' Uncomment line bellow to save appointment
        '.Save
    End With
    
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olApt = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(Rng As Range)
    ' Ron de Bruin: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm
    
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    Rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         fileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry it seems to crash at this point. "With TempWB.Sheets(1)" is there anything I would need to adapt in this line?

Comment: Did you replaced the range as I told?

Comment: Yes I did this.

Comment: I just put your range and it works! Update your post and paste the procedure ``CreateAppointment`` with the changes you made.

Comment: Thanks! Which range did you use exactly?

Comment: I just updated the ``CreateAppointment`` procedure with your range and set the ``RowCount`` variable to 5 just for testing. This works!

Comment: Hmm it just stops at the same line I previously mentioned. Is there anything else I would need to change?

Comment: I will also update my post.

Comment: What did you update in your post?

Comment: Create a new blank workbook, insert a standard module, paste the code, set your range in a sheet and run it to see if it continues to stop.

Comment: Your code as is, will not work. Put an image of your range and recipients so it can be adapted to the ``CreateApointment`` procedure

Comment: Its ok, I will try again some other time .Thanks.